# Best practices for service/merchant handling bitcoins

Tags: security, coldstorage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to safely host a high volume online transactional wallet?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5347/best-way-to-safely-host-a-high-volume-online-transactional-wallet)

There have been numerous incidents where bitcoin services have been hacked and large amounts of bitcoins have been stolen. There was even an exchange that accidentally deleted its only copy of its bitcoin wallet.

Which best practices should a service or merchant follow when handling bitcoins?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best conveyed using the wiki:

- http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Securing_online_services